# Syntax for regex in IF statment

Tags: bash, regex

I'm trying to come up with the syntax for a regex in an IF statement, but I'm not quickly having success...  Can anyone lend a quick hand please?

```
if [[ "$path/$file" =~ .{txt,doc,docx,xlsx,rtf} ]];
   then
    echo "hello"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty close to a [glob pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching). Try

```
if [[ "$path/$file" == *.{txt,doc,docx,xlsx,rtf} ]];
```

If you really want a regular expression

```
if [[ "$path/$file" =~ \.(txt|doc|docx|xlsx|rtf)$ ]];
```

Finding a regular expression tutorial online left as an exercise ...

Comment: if [[ "$path/$file" =~ \.(txt|rtf|doc|xls)$ ]];
then
echo "hello"
fi