# How to compare two links if they're correct

Tags: command-line, server, bash

I have a question. I'll first show to code (written in bash).

```
#! /bin/bash

oldlink="https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-media-server-new/1.21.1.3876-3c3adfcb4/debian/plexmediaserver_1.21.1.3876-3c3adfcb4_amd64.deb"
newlink=$(curl -s -S https://plex.tv/pms/downloads/5.json | grep -o 'Ubuntu (16.04+) / Debian (8+) - Intel/AMD 64-bit","build":"linux-x86_64","distro":"debian","url":"https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-media-server-new/.*/debian/plexmediaserver_.*_amd64.deb","checksum":".*"},{"label":"Ubuntu (16.04+) / Debian (8+) - ARMv8' | grep -o https://.*.deb)
correctlink="https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-media-server-new/.*/debian/plexmediaserver_.*_amd64.deb"

if [[ $newlink = $correctlink ]]
then
        echo "new link is correct"
else
        echo "new link isn't correct"
fi
```

I have a link that'll never change (to be honest it will sometimes, because this code is part of a bigger script, but for now we'll say it's static)(oldlink).
The newlink (newlink) gets updated everytime the script is run. The output of the command after newlink, will look exactly like the link at oldlink. Aside from the version numbers (1.21.1.3876_3c3adfcb4) if there's a new version.

When the code above is run, it means that newlink is different from oldlink (most of the times new version, because the version number in the link will change ofcourse, so the link will be different). It will never run if the links are the same. They'll always be different when this code is run.

What I want to do is compare oldlink and newlink with each other. oldlink and newlink are different from each other. I want to check if the difference is the version number or that it's a different part of the link.

**how it should work**

```
oldlink = "https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-media-server-new/1.21.1.3876-3c3adfcb4/debian/plexmediaserver_1.21.1.3876-3c3adfcb4_amd64.deb"

newlink = "https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-media-server-new/1.22.4.3876-3c3adfcb4/debian/plexmediaserver_1.22.4.3876-3c3adfcb4_amd64.deb"

[echo] new link is correct

==============================================

old link = "https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-media-server-new/1.21.1.3876-3c3adfcb4/debian/plexmediaserver_1.21.1.3876-3c3adfcb4_amd64.deb"

newlink = "https://this.is.something.else.hello/plex-media-server-new/1.21.1.3876-3c3adfcb4/blablabla/plexmediaserver_1.21.1.3876-3c3adfcb4_amd64.deb"

[echo] new link isn't correct
```

So, when the version number changes, it's okay. When something else of the link changes, it's not okay. That's how it should work.

How I want to check that, was to compare the newlik with a standard (correctlink). If they match, it's a correct link. Because correctlink only matches with the newlink if the versionnumber is different. Nothing else can be different.

**How it actually works**

It gives random outputs. Sometimes it gives it right, sometimes wrong. I haven't been able to find a structure in when it does it wrong and when right. I have a feeling it has to do with the * in the correctlink. I have tried with .* and * but that didn't change the outcome.

How can I fix this or is there a better way to do this. I prefer a better/shorter/faster/easier way than a fix.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex pattern matching:

```
[[ "$newlink" =~ $correctlink ]]
```

See also:

- [Syntax for regex in IF statment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578158/syntax-for-regex-in-if-statment)
- [How can I match a string with a regex in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420994/how-can-i-match-a-string-with-a-regex-in-bash)

Comment: it worked perfectly. Thanks!